# The sidebar of my site is overflowed at 100% height how do I fix it?

Tags: html, css, web

So I have an unfinished site with only a sidebar and after doing the whole thing I realised that whenever the content in #overflow div overflows and is scrollable it will exceed the 100% height. I really cant figure it out how to fix it. Please help me my mind is gonna explode Idk what's going on

Here's the whole code cause I'm having trouble putting jsfiddle link to this site

```js
var defaultText = "Googol anything...";
var searchBox = document.getElementById("search");

//default text after load
searchBox.value = defaultText;

//on focus behaviour
searchBox.onfocus = function() {
if (this.value == defaultText) {//clear text field
this.value = '';
}
}

//on blur behaviour
searchBox.onblur = function() {
if (this.value == "") {//restore default text
this.value = defaultText;
}
}
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
min-width: 800px;
height: 100%;
white-space: initial;
word-break: break-word;
font-size: 14px;
overflow-x: auto;
}
#sidebar{
width: 180px;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
background-color: #b39bd9;
position: fixed;
}
#sidebar a{
color: white;
}
.logo{
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 155px;
}
.logo-margin{
 margin-left: 5px; 
}
.logo:hover {
    background-color: #ede2ff;
}
#overflow{
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
height: 100%;
}
#side-ul{
 margin-left: 15px; 
}
#side-ul ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#side-ul li:hover {
  color: gray;
}
#side-ul a{
text-decoration: none;
}
#side-ul li:hover {
background-color: #ede2ff;
}
#side-ul li:hover a{
background-color: #ede2ff;
color: gray;
}
.youtube{
 width: 170px;
 height: 127px;
}
.gcse-search input{
width: 133px;
height: 20;
font-size: 14px;
}
.searchbar{
 padding: 2px; 
}
#links{
 margin-left: 5px; 
}
.big{
 font-size: 22px;
 color: black;
}
button{
    height: 20px;
 border-right: gray 2px solid;
 border-bottom: gray 2px solid;
 border-left: white 2px solid;
 border-top: white 2px solid;
 background-color: lightgray;
}
 button:hover {
    height: 20px;
 border-left: gray 2px solid;
 border-top: gray 2px solid;
 border-right: white 2px solid;
 border-bottom: white 2px solid;
 background-color: lightgray;
}
.go{
 float: right;
 margin-right: 2px; 
}
```

```html
<html\>
<head\>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
<div class="logo-margin">
<a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/eleanor.gif" title="Eleanor - Index" alt="Eleanor - Index" ></a><br>
</div>
<div>
<div class="gcse-search">
    <form method="get" action="https://eleanorfox.neocities.org/resultsonly.html">
        <div class="searchbar">
<input type="text" name="q" id="search" value="" />
<button class="go" type="submit">Go!</button>

</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="gcse-searchresults-only"></div>
</div>
<div id="overflow">
<div id="links">
<div class="big"><b>Social medias</b></div>
<div id="side-ul">
<div style="margin-top: 5px;">
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUtm-hXtk58F0mqw8B_xLbQ" title="Youtube" alt="Youtube">Youtube</a></li>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/EleanorFoxQueen##" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter">Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.off---line.com/profile?id=523" title="Offline" alt="Offline">Offline (2007 FB copycat)</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/Eleanor_Fox_69" title="Reddit" alt="Reddit">Reddit</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="big"><b>My collection</b></div>
<div id="side-ul">
<div style="margin-top: 5px;">
<ul>
<li><a href="my-fav-hyperlinks.html" title="Favourite hyperlinks" alt="Favourite hyperlinks">Favourite hyperlinks</a></li>
<li><a href="my-vinyl-records.html" title="Vinyl records" alt="Vinyl records">Vinyl records I bought/got</a></li>
<li><a href="my-vinyl-records.html" title="Favourite PC/laptop/mobile devices" alt="Favourite PC/laptop/mobile devices">Favourite PC/laptop/mobile devices</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="big"><b>Personal stuff</b></div>
<div id="side-ul">
<div style="margin-top: 5px;">
<ul>
<li><a href="diary.html" title="Diary of a...me" alt="Diary of a...me">Diary of a...me</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="big"><b>Rss</b></div>
<div id="side-ul">
<div style="margin-top: 5px;">
<ul>
<li><a href="80s-pc-and-tvs.html" title="Major updates" alt="Major updates">Silly stuff</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<iframe class="youtube" style="margin-top: 10px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oMHLkcc9I9c?si=a7OmIO1OEw_HxgJm" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I really dont know what to try

Comment: `it will exceed the 100% height` ... but it doesnt. Just tried it. Could you clarify what you mean by "exceed"?

Comment: @GetSet Ahh so when you zoom in and it overflows the first time the scrollbar wont show up but then you zoom in one more time it will but it overflows. That's what the problem is and it's driving me nuts